# Why cant i install UKUU this is what i've tried please Help!

Tags: kernel, updates, 19.04

[image]

Im running 19.04 Ubuntu.
Kernal version is 5.0.0-32-generic
im trying to update to a more recent Kernal.

im trying to use UKUU.

Comment: ukuu is now a paying app, once for a lifetime, all computers. Very cool software that deserves the $11 imo.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility (UKUU) has now moved to a paid licensing model and is no longer available free in the Ubuntu Software Centre with the latest release for Ubuntu v19.

The cost of a personal license is $11.

If you want to install a kernel newer than the one available in Ubuntu for reasons like some new important feature, better hardware support, or in case they fix some critical issue you're having with the default Ubuntu kernel, like some device not working, you can use the Mainline Kernel PPA. https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

This is not an actual PPA that you can add on your system like a Launchpad PPA and instead, you need to manually download and install the DEB packages. To make this process easier and optionally be notified when new kernels are available in the Mainline PPA, there are various tools you can use, and this article presents two such tools, one that uses a graphical user interface, and another one that can be used from the command line. Both utilities support not only Ubuntu, but also Ubuntu-based Linux distributions like Linux Mint.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!. i will try mainline.!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider upvoting/marking as accepted to assist others with the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade Latest Linux Kernel In Ubuntu using UKTools
You can easily upgrade latest Linux kernel in Ubuntu automatically with this tools. You can also use this tool to upgrade Linux kernel to the latest version in Linux Mint.
Download and install UkTools:

```
git clone https://github.com/usbkey9/uktools && cd uktools

make
```

To upgrade Kernel:

```
$ sudo uktools-upgrade
```

To remove old and unused kernels in Ubuntu :

```
$ sudo uktools-purge
```

no need to ukuu ;)